# How to set Spring component scan in the Spring YML configuration file?

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

I can see that I can do component scan and restrict what packages are scanned using XML file.

```
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>
</beans>
```

How can I do the same in YML file?

Comment: I don't think that is intended, yml are spring-boot's properties file, and not spring-core configuration resources. You can however subclass `ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser` to make it load a yml file if that's what you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YML is just to load properties, refer to this [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml).

> 24.6 Using YAML instead of Properties YAML is a superset of JSON, and as such is a very convenient format for specifying hierarchical
>   configuration data. The SpringApplication class will automatically
>   support YAML as an alternative to properties whenever you have the
>   SnakeYAML library on your classpath.

This is also explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

> You can also use YAML ('.yml') files as an alternative to
>   '.properties'.

So you cannot define/configure beans using YML.

Answer (score 0):

that is unnecessary，because yml file belongs to spring boot，